# Check if an URL is relative to another (ie. they are on the same host)

Tags: python, url

I have a base HTTP URL and a list of other HTTP URLs. I’m writing a simple crawler/link checker as a study (hence, no pre-written tool needs to be suggested) that checks if the base URL has any broken links, and recursively crawls all the other “internal” pages (ie. pages linked from the base URL within the same site) with the same intentions. At the end I have to output the list of links with their status (external/internal, and a warning for each links that are actually internal but presented as absolute URLs.

So far I [succeeded](https://github.com/gergelypolonkai/link-checker) in checking all the links and doing the crawling using the request and BeautifulSoup libraries, but I cannot find an already written way to check if two absolute URLs point to the same site (other than splitting the URLs along slashes, which seems ugly to me). Is there a well-known library for this?

Comment: Do you mean something like urlparse ?https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Exactly! I wonder how I missed it. I will post my solution with this tomorrow morning (CEST). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At the end I went with [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (kudos goes for @padraic-cunningham for pointing me to it). At the beginning of the code I parse the “base URL” (ie. the one I begin crawling with):

```
base_parts = urlparse.urlparse(base_url)
```

then for each link I find (e.g. with `for a in soup.find_all('a'):`

```
link_parts = urlparse.urlparse(a.get('href'))
```

At this point I have to compare the URL scheme (I consider links to the same site with different URL scheme, http or https, different; I may make this comparison optional in the future):

```
internal = base_parts.scheme == link_parts.scheme \
           and base_parts.netloc == link_parts.netloc
```

and by here, internal will be `True` if the link points to the same server (with the same scheme) as my base URL. You can check the final result [here](https://github.com/gergelypolonkai/link-checker/blob/master/crawler.py).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a crawler my self. I hope that this will help you. Basically what I did is to add the url to sites like /2/2/3/index.php, which will make the site as http://www.website.com/2/2/3/index.php . Then I inserted all the websites to an array that checks if I visited this website before and if I do it will not visit there. Also, if there are some unrelated websites in this site, like a link to an youtube video, then it will not crawl youtube or any other website which is not "website related" as well.

For your question, I recommend you to put all the visited website in to an array, and check the array with a for loop. if a URL is the same as the array then print it.

I'm not sure that this is what you desired but at least I try. I'm not using BeautifulSoup and it still works so consider to leave that module aside.

My script (More like part of it. I also got exception check so don't panic) :

```
__author__ = "Sploit"


# This part is about import the default python modules and the modules that the user have to download
# If the module does not exist, the script asks him to install that specific module

import os  # This module provides a portable way of using operating system dependent functionality
import urllib  # The urllib module provides a simple interface for network resource access
import urllib2  # The urllib2 module provides a simple interface for network resource access
import time  # This module provides various time-related functions
import urlparse  # This module defines a standard interface to break URL strings up in components
                 # to combine the components back into a URL string, and to convert a relative URL to an absolute URL given a base URL.
import mechanize

print ("Which website would you like to crawl?")
website_url = raw_input("--> ")

# Ads http:// to the given URL because it is the only way to check for server response
# If the user will add to the URL directions then they will be deleted
# Example: 'https://moz.com/learn/seo/external-link' will turn to 'https://moz.com/'
if website_url.split('//')[0] != 'http:' and website_url.split('//')[0] != 'https:':
    website_url = 'http://' + website_url
website_url = website_url.split('/')[0] + '//' + website_url.split('/')[2]

# The user will stuck in a loop until a valid website is exist, using the application layer of the OSI module, HTTP Protocol
while True:
    try:
        if urllib2.urlopen(website_url).getcode() != 200:
            print ("Invalid URL given. Which website would you like to crawl?")
            website_url = raw_input("--> ")
        else:
            break
    except:
        print ("Invalid URL given. Which website would you like to crawl?")
        website_url = raw_input("--> ")

# This part is the actual the Web Crawler
# What it does is to search for links
# All the URLs that are not the websites URLs are printed in a txt file named "Non website links"


fake_browser = mechanize.Browser()  # Set the starting point for the spider and initialize the a mechanize browser object
urls = [website_url]  # Create lists for the URLs that the script should go through
visited = [website_url]  # Create lists that we have visited in, to avoid multiplies
text_file = open("Non website links.txt", "w")  # We create a txt file for all the URLs that are not the websites URLs
text_file_url = open("Website links.txt", "w")  # We create a txt file for all the URLs that are the websites URLs

print ("Crawling : " + website_url)
print ("The crawler started at " + time.asctime(time.localtime()) + ". This may take a couple of minutes")  # To let the user know when the crawler started to work
# Since the amount of urls in the list is dynamic we just let the spider go until some last url didn't have new ones on the website
while len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        fake_browser.open(urls[0])
        urls.pop(0)
        for link in fake_browser.links():  # A loop which looking for all the images in the website
            new_website_url = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)  # Create a new url with the websites link that is acceptable as HTTP
            if new_website_url not in visited and website_url in new_website_url:  # If we have been in this website, don't enter the URL to the list, to avoid multiplies
                visited.append(new_website_url)
                urls.append(new_website_url)
                print ("Found: " + new_website_url)  # Print all the links that the crawler found
                text_file_url.write(new_website_url + '\n')  # Print the non-website URL to the txt file
            elif new_website_url not in visited and website_url not in new_website_url:
                visited.append(new_website_url)
                text_file.write(new_website_url + '\n')  # Print the non-website URL to the txt file
    except:
        print ("Link couldn't be opened")
        urls.pop(0)

text_file.close()  # Close the txt file, to prevent anymore writing to it
text_file_url.close()  # Close the txt file, to prevent anymore writing to it
print ("A txt file with all the website links has been created in your folder")
print ("Finished!!")
```

Comment: This is somewhat I already did, except you use mechanize instead of request+beautifulsoup (which I will consider, too). Wy goal now is to check if a link is absolute bet internal; ie. an absolute "http://gergely.polonkai.eu/blog/" link instead of a plain ”/blog/" on my site.